# Where is the best place for running unit tests: Dockerfile or CI-system (e.g. Jenkins)?

Tags: docker, unit-testing, jenkins, testing, continuous-integration

Write plz pros and cons for place for unit-tests (and other tests)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is good to build your image after all your unit tests passed. But it depends on your CI solution and your project too.